Numbers app keeps deleting data. Why?
I use Numbers app on my iPhone and MacBook to edit documents stored on iCloud. Sometimes the data doesn't sync immediately, though eventually it will.
But other times it will "sync" by replacing a later edit made on my Mac with an earlier one edited on my iPhone, thus erasing a large amount of new data. It won't even notify me (it used to ask me which version I wanted to keep) and I often won't notice until it's too late. It's been happening continually lately. How do I solve this problem?

I’m not sure how we’re going to be better than Apple support to understand what’s happening with your iCloud sync.
If you can capture some data on versions, maybe you can compare dates and times on your two devices and on the iCloud web app for numbers and avoid a support call?

https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers-icloud/restore-earlier-versions-gile60ace11a/icloud


Thank you! The UI for that on Sequoia is a nightmare, but at least if you have the patience to click through and manually load the previous versions it's a relief to see the data is still there. (I obviously had no idea about this feature.) Now to understand what's going wrong with sync...

Yes @h_undatus a life saver when versions works - good luck. Feel free to edit my answer or propose and accept your own once you sort it out. Data loss is the absolute worst…
